# Can't figure out how to align HTML/CSS Divs

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align horizontally an image and paragraph of text next to each other within my main div element of my web page.

The divs are wrapped like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="image"> 
    </div>
    <div id="paragraph">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Is this the right layout? If so, what CSS do I need?

Comment: The code didn't come through in your post, you should edit it and add it back in. But generally, yes this would require CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set both of the inner divs to

`display: inline-block;`

Check out this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/m8athtLp/light/

Answer (score 0):

You can do using two way:
Firstly, From your markup, You can use css to `float: left` image and `float: right` paragraph.
Secondly,

```
<pre><div id="main">
  <img src="images/img.jpg" alt=""> 
  <p>your text</p>
</div></pre>
```

For this this code you can use `float: left` for image, paragraph text auto align right

Thanks